# Sorting Elements from different DIV's

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have 3 div columns as below

```
<div class="col col-4 clist">
 <div data-seq="3">3</div>
 <div data-seq="5">5</div>
 <div data-seq="9">9</div>
</div>
<div class="col col-4 clist">
 <div data-seq="8">8</div>
 <div data-seq="7">7</div>
 <div data-seq="1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="col col-4 clist">
 <div data-seq="4">4</div>
 <div data-seq="2">2</div>
 <div data-seq="6">6</div>
</div>
```

I want to sort this inner div's in ascending order as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. It doesn't matter if it all get sorted and displayed in a single div and/or displayed in 3 different div's. For the same purpose I am using the below written js from http://jsfiddle.net/f5mC9/

```
var contacts = $('div.clist'), cont = contacts.children('div');

cont.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
            var astts = $(a).data('seq');
            var bstts = $(b).data('seq')
            //return astts - bstts;
            return (astts > bstts) ? (astts > bstts) ? 1 : 0 : -1;
        });

contacts.append(cont);
```

I am not able to sort elements from different div's. If all the elements are in single div the code works.

Please help me out.

And heartfully thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop over each `.clist` element using `each()` and sort the child `div` elements within it. Something like this:

```
$('div.clist').each(function () {
    var $cont = $(this).children('div').sort(function (a, b) {
        return ($(a).data('seq') > $(b).data('seq')) ? 1 : -1;
    });
    $(this).append($cont);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7hF9/)

Comment: ...because `.sort()` is not a jQuery function. It's an in-built array function. Which means that you weren't sorting on a jQuery object (as you normally are with function overloads) rather on all the objects matched by your selector as an array.

Comment: @dhpratik It's really not! edit: Unless...you mean you want 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan fiddle is not working as intended. it is displaying in order but of that particular div

Comment: @dhpratik thats what you asked for, was it not? Can you please edit your OP with more detail of what you need if this is not it.

Comment: @RGraham i want the output as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

Since you're fine with the results being in a single div, simply extract all the fields into a new div first:

```
<div id="result">
</div>

$('div.clist').each(function() {
    $('#result').html($('#result').html() + $(this).html());
});
```

Then go about your business and just sort it:

```
var $cont = $('#result').children('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    var astts = $(a).data('seq');
    var bstts = $(b).data('seq')
    return (astts > bstts) ? 1 : -1;
});

$('#result').append($cont);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pSC98/1/